# OLAP Cubes get incremented folder names in SAS 9.2

Tags: sas, data-warehouse, olap

When updating/Creating cubes in SAS 9.2 the Cubes in folder c:\OLAP is not overwritten.
The folder names is incremented with numbers :
C:\OLAP\Departments1
C:\OLAP\Departments2 
and so on..

In 9.1.3 this didnt happen. Anyone know how to turn this feature of, or why it is like this?

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this happen if the process rebuilding the cube is killed before it finished building the cube.

I guess these numbered folders are related to ["generations" used with incremental cube updates introduced in 9.2](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/olapug/59574/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a003241630.htm).

What's your PROC OLAP code? Do you run PROC OLAP DELETE_PHYSICAL (or DELETE) before updating/building the cube?